# Haskell Binarysearchtree, checker function problem

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, binary-search-tree, binary-search

I would like to write a function in haskell, which checks if a Binarytree with this specific structure:

```
data BB a = L | K a (BB a) (BB a) deriving Show
```

is a *Binary**Search**Tree* or not. An example for a BinarySearchTree:

```
baumA = K 5 (K 3 (K 1 L L) L) (K 7 L (K 12 (K 9 L L) L))
```

The function I wrote works, but gives me some warnings im unclear of why they're appearing. The warnings are:

> "Pattern match has inaccessible right hand side
> In an equation for `hilf': hilf (K w L L) acc 0 = ..."

and

> "Pattern match is redundant
> In an equation for `hilf': hilf (K w L L) acc 1 = ..."

The code for my funciton is this here:

```
isBinarySearchTree :: Ord a => BB a -> Bool
isBinarySearchTree (K initial l r) = hilf l initial 0 && hilf r initial 1 
-- "0" means left side and "1" means right side


hilf L _ _ = True -- neutral case

hilf (K w l r) acc 0                                
    | w < acc && hilf l w 0 && hilf r w 1 = True
    | otherwise = False

hilf (K w L L) acc 0
    | w < acc  = True
    | otherwise = False

hilf (K w l r) acc 1
    | w > acc && hilf l w 0 && hilf r w 1 = True
    | otherwise = False

hilf (K w L L) acc 1
    | w > acc  = True
    | otherwise = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `hilf` will never visit `hilf (K w L L) acc 0`, since `hilf (K w l r) acc 0` matches even if `l` and `r` are (both) `L`. The patterns for `hilf (K w L L) acc 0` and `hilf (K w L L) acc 1` this will never be visited.

But even if that is the case the checker will not work: a node is not a lift or a right one. Most nodes are inner nodes, and thus have to satisfy two constraints: the value should be less than a given value and more than a certain value.

You can work with a helper function that has two `Maybe a`s as constraints. If it is a `Nothing` that means that the constraint is "not active", whereas `Just x` means that the value should be greater (or smaller) than a given value. We thus can make two helper functions:

```
checkOrd1 :: Ord a => Maybe a -> a -> Bool
checkOrd1 Nothing _ = True
checkOrd1 (Just x) y = x < y

checkOrd2 :: Ord a => a -> Maybe a -> Bool
checkOrd2 _ Nothing = True
checkOrd2 x (Just y) = x < y

checkOrd :: Ord a => Maybe a -> a -> Maybe a -> Bool
checkOrd l x g = checkOrd1 l x && checkOrd2 x g
```

then our `isBinarySearchTree` calls the helper function with at that moment two disabled constraints:

```
isBinarySearchTree :: Ord a => BB a -> Bool
isBinarySearchTree tree = hilf Nothing Nothing tree
```

The `hilf` for a leave `L` is always true, for a node `K` we thus split it up in two extra checks:

```
hilf :: Ord a => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> BB a -> Bool
hilf _ _ L = True
hilf l g (K v left right) = checkOrd l v g && hilf … left && hilf … right
```

where I leave filling in the `…` parts as an exercise. You here thus should reuse the constraints you inerhit, but use the value `v` as a new upperbound for the left subtree and lowerbound as the right subtree.

Comment: Thank you really much for that, i didn't notice it was under so i just swapped some lines of code ! But i don't understand why it shoudn't work now, since we only have left or right roots. In my testing its working and it gives the correct output for wrong trees: False and for correct trees : True.

Comment: @AJ.beProgramming: it will for example return true for `K 5 L (K 10 (K 2 L L) L)`, but here the `K 2 L L` node is invalid, since it is less than `5`, which is the root node.